# 16.04 F11 is broken for gnome-terminal

Tags: 16.04

I use `F11` to toggle between full screen window and the other window size that I set. I only just installed 16.04. Chrome and Firefox toggle fine using `F11`, but gnome-terminal goes into full screen mode doesn't go back to the original size.

`ctrl+super+up` and `ctrl+super+down` work fine

Any suggestion how to fix this will be much appreciated.

UPDATE:
This is a known bug for gnome-terminal on 16.04, see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1573563).
Please mark yourself as affected by this bug if you want it to be fixed by the devs.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your shortcuts might be disabled.

Under the `Edit` menu, select `Preferences`, then go to the `Shortcuts` tab and make sure `Enable shortcuts` is selected:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, but I haven't touched any settings and I checked `F11` is set for Full screen toggle. By pressing `F11` gnome-terminal goes into full screen mode ! but if you press `F11` again it doesn't return to the original size ! So right now `F11` is one way toggle.